# Use jump host to connect to one server then check the disk space in other servers

Tags: linux, bash, script

I can connect to servers using a jumphost. I am trying to write a shell script to login to multiple servers and check the disk space and send an email if the space is over 90%. My problem is that in the jump host I cannot create the script, restricted access. I am trying to create the shell script in one of the servers. I found a script that checks for space, my issue is that the script runs and when it tries to login to the first server, the login fails since I am already logged in one server. What I am trying to do is run the script while login to one server, the script should run in the background and check for all servers.

Comment: you can add an IF statement to validate if you are alrady logged in, try `if [ $(who | grep username) == 0 ]` if the command returns 0 that means the user is not logged in and you can run your code

Comment: I am logged in a server through ssh from jumphost. I am trying to connect to different servers. How can I incorporate logging out from the server and login to other servers?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
for i in server1 server2 server3
do

ssh $i df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $4 " " $5 }' | while read output;
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge 80 ]; then
    echo "Running out of space \"$partition - ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" |
     mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" kkk$yahoo
fi
done
done

Comment: oh I undestand you now, let me check it

Comment: Try something like this `ssh user@ipaddress 'my_script.sh && exit'` you need to perform an exit after you finish the execution of the command and before you try to log in into the next server. It is a little hard read your code in that comment, you can update your question to make it more readable, but i think you can put an exit at the end of your ssh command, let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a ssh proxy using `ProxyCommand` in `~/.ssh/config` on the host you are initiating the connection from.

Then you simply provide what you want to do on the final host without even bothering with anything on the jumphost

You set it up like this in ssh config

```
Host 10.0.4.*
    ProxyCommand ssh -q jumphost_user@jumphost.server nc -q0 %h %p
```

Then whenever you ssh to any 10.0.4.* host you are going through the jumphost without any hassle.
As you can see it works by setting up a `netcat` proxy to the final host

and

```
ssh 10.0.4.10 '/usr/path/to/check_command'
```

on the initial host will give you the check_disk output from the final host, like the diagram below

| initial host | --- ssh finalhost ---> | jumphost | --- netcat proxy ---> | final host |

You can read about it in more detail here
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/